# Как сделать так, чтобы к переменной прибавлялось 1 каждую секунду?

Tags: swift

Есть переменная Int и нужно, чтобы каждую секунду к ней прибавлялась 1 , независимо от того, что делает юзер, то есть в фоне в реальном времени, не от работы кнопки и тд.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать данный метод

Comment: банально сохранить время начала отсчёта. а когда нужно получить значение, отнимать сохранённое время от текущего.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myValue : Int = 0
var timer : Timer?
self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0 ,
repeats: true, block: { timer in
myValue += 1})
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]